# checkbox - check at least one box has been selected

Tags: javascript, checkbox

To validate a statement I have made sure that the checkboxes and quantities are consistent with each other but I haven't made sure that at least one product has been selected or a total quantity greater than zero is supplied. How would I do this?

```
if (((document.form1.summer.checked) && (summer2012 <= 0)) ||
    ((document.form1.autumn.checked) && (autumn2012 <= 0)) ||
    ((document.form1.winter.checked) && (winter2012 <= 0))) 
{
    alertmsg = alertmsg + "Please enter Quantity" + "\n";
}
else if (((!document.form1.summer.checked) && (summer2012 > 0)) ||
    ((!document.form1.autumn.checked) && (autumn2012 > 0)) ||
    ((!document.form1.winter.checked) && (winter2012 > 0))) 
{
    alertmsg = alertmsg + "Please choose Product" + "\n";

}
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td align="right">Summer 2012</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="summer" value="Summer 2012" />
    </td>
    <td align="center" width="69">
        <div align="right">20.00</div>
    </td>
    <td width="216">
        <input name="summer2012" type="text" size="5" value="0" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right">Autumn 2012</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="autumn" value="Autumn 2012" />
    </td>
    <td align="center" width="69">
        <div align="right">20.00</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="autumn2012" type="text" size="5" value="0" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right">Winter 2012</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="winter" value="Winter 2012" />
    </td>
    <td align="center" width="69">
        <div align="right">20.00</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="winter2012" type="text" size="5" value="0" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can we see the html too?

Comment: I assume that first `if` block is supposed to be checking for `summer.checked` and not `ch1.checked` ?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to already have a test to confirm that for any checked box there must be a corresponding (positive) amount, and a second test to confirm that any positive amount also has a check against it.

All you therefore need to do is check that *some* checkbox is checked.

```
var f = document.form1;
if (f.summer.checked || f.autumn.checked || f.winter.checked) {
    // we're OK!
}
```

Comment: thank you.  I was told that my checkboxes and quantities were consistent with each other but it didn't make sure that at least one product had been selected or a total quantity greater than zero was supplied

Comment: @user2073133 sure, so this _additional_ test ensures that at least one has been selected.  Your original tests (done before this one) do the rest.

Comment: thanks Alnitak.  I have written a regular expression for the quantity and the maximum they can order is 500 for each (summer, autumn, winter).  The expression is - var chkquantity = ^([1-9]?\d|[1-4]\d{2}|500)$/

Comment: I'm not sure if the test is correct - if ((chkquantity.test(quantity)== false) 
{
alertmsg = alertmsg + "Please limit each magazine to 500 copies or less:" + "\n";
}

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would check if any checkbox has been checked:

```
var checkboxElements = [
    document.form1.ch1,
    document.form1.autumn,
    document.form1.winter,
    document.form1.summer
];

function anyChecked(checkboxElements) {
    for(var i = 0; i < checkboxElements.length; i++)
        if(checkboxElements[i].checked)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```